# Adding audio to mp4 using ffmpeg at certain offset gives output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I am attempting to add audio to a MP4 file using ffmpeg at a specific time, eventually I also want the audio to only play until a certain point, so if you can help with that also that would be great, otherwise if you can just assist me in figuring out what is causing this error.

The arguments I use

```
-y "E:\Documents\Content Bar/Photo Booth\PhotosDrop\2018-05-15 14-01-16OUT.mp4" -itsoffset  -i "E:\Downloads\wetransfer-250b26\05 Call of Love.mp3" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -shortest "E:\Documents\Content Bar\Photo Booth\PhotosDrop\2018-05-15 14-01-16OUTOUT.mp4"
```

This results in the following error:

```
ffmpeg version N-81646-gc19da0c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 55.101 / 57. 55.101
  libavformat    57. 48.103 / 57. 48.103
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 62.100 /  6. 62.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Output #0, mp4, to 'E:\Documents\Content Bar/Photo Booth\PhotosDrop\2018-05-15 14-01-16OUT.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out using the following command

```
-i "E:\Documents\Content Bar/Photo Booth\PhotosDrop\2018-05-15 14-01-16OUT.mp4" -i "E:\Downloads\wetransfer-250b26\05 Call of Love.mp3" -filter_complex "[1]atrim=end=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aud1];[aud1]adelay=6000|6000[aud];[0][aud]amix" -c:v copy out.mp4
```